# Eigen DenseBase segmentation fault

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, eigen

I don't know why the following gives a segmentation fault.

Test:

```
#include <Eigen/Eigen>
using namespace Eigen;
template<typename Derived>
inline void f(DenseBase<Derived> x) { 
    x(0, 0) = 1;
}
int main() {
    Matrix<double, Dynamic, Dynamic> x(3, 4);
    f(x);
}
```

Comment: oh. forgot to reference. and it is pass by value. my god... but i still don't know why this happens.

Comment: Found the answer: https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TopicPassingByValue.html Pass by value does not respect memory alignment. And wrong memory alignment can crash the program.

Comment: That is not the reason. `DenseBase` is an empty base class, which gets cast to `Derived` inside `f` and then will access non-existing member variables.

Comment: I filed a bug for this issue: http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/bz/show_bug.cgi?id=1587